# (WiX Toolset) Make Bootstrapper application not show the uninstall screen when executed after an install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

So, this may sound strange at first but hear me out.

I am currently using wix to create an installer for a company. It is running on the WiX Bootstrapper Project template.

This is not an installer in the usual sense but rather is used as a tool to let the user choose a variety of different prerequisites and tools that he wants to install. Because of the nature of this installer we don't want it to show up in the control panel and we don't want the user to use the uninstall function either. Essentially we want it to be something the user uses to set up a workspace of his choosing, and if he forgets something, he just runs the installer again and installs the forgotten tool.

So once the user has used the installer, I don't want it to have any traces left of the installation except for the installed products.

I have managed to make the installer not show up in the control panel, but I haven't figured out how to not make the uninstall screen show up once the installer has already been executed once and it is run again. I think it has to do with the registry key being set automatically by WiX on installation.

Is there anyway to disable or bypass this system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fighting your tool's design if you go this way. Perhaps instead of trying to hide it entirely, see if you can make the maintenance experience more like what you want. If you can't, you may be better off writing a customized launcher that kicks off separate installations upon request. This (theoretical) launcher wouldn't have to keep track of itself the way wix does.